# Signalr Calling Hub Method from Code Behind Ajax Call

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I am running the stock signalr example and trying to modify the code and try something differnt. What I am wanting is on a front end button press to call an ajax call and from there call a hub method. When I do this I am not hitting my breakpoint in my hub method

Front end code change:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
$('#sendmessage').click(function () {
// Call the Send method on the hub.
$.ajax({

url: '/home/MyTest/',
type: "POST",
success: function () {
alert("done");
}, error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
alert("failed");
}

});
//chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
// Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
$('#message').val('').focus();
});
});
```

In HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyTest()
{
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.send("a","b");
}
```

ChatHub.cs

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
public void Send(string name, string message)
{
// Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hub method on the server doesn't get executed... What

`var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.send("a","b");`

is saying is : On every client that has an open/active connection to the Hub, I'm invoking a *`send`* function *on the client*. Not on the Hub on the server.

Comment: ahhhhhhh ... thank you. I was pulling my hair out. So then in that function call "send". I would invoke the call to the server correct

Comment: That's one way to do it, yeah for sure

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark